# Android: Update system images from own build so that emulator reflects changes in core java files

Tags: android, jar, android-emulator

I built my own android images from source which works without errors.
Now I made some changes (mostly log messages) to core java files (in framework/base/services).
I can now run 'mmm framework/base/services/java' to compile and update the services.jar.
This seems to work without error.
When I now start the emulator (created by the inital build process) the changes are not reflected in logcat.

Therefore I think the modified services.jar is not included in the system image used by the emulator.

Is it possible to update these images with some command?
Do I have to completely rebuild everything or change the image manually?

For changing the image manually I found some tutorial here: 
[Modifying .IMG Files](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_eMMC_Booting#Modifying_.IMG_Files)

That is really much work for just changing one or two lines of code...

I also tried using the following:

```
$ adb remount
$ ./adb push ~/android/out/target/product/generic/system/framework/services.jar /system/framework/services.jar
failed to copy 
'/home/devusr/android/out/target/product/generic/system/framework/services.jar' to '/system/framework/services.jar': No space left on device
```

I think there is no space left because it is a fixed emulator image...

Comment: There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307532/android-source-framework-modify-rebuild-but-become-effective-in-emulator/49428228#answer-49428228)  .  It seems like these are the same question, but I'm not sure which is a dup of which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had the same problem, if i got your question correctly. Try using

```
mmm framework/base/services/java
make
```

Use make on the top android source folder to recreate the system images and install all relevant files. 
Don't worry normally it won't rebuild everything.

Comment: Yes this works, but it's just the same as `make` by itself, isn't it?