# Android source framework modify rebuild but become effective in emulator

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, android-source

i modify **/framework/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java** some logcat output string.

and i try to use different ways to rebuild it:

**make -jN** from top folder or

**mmm /framework/base -jN** or

**mmm /framework/base/services -jN**

and then i get a new output file in **/out/target/product/generic_x86/system/framework/x86/services.odex**

and then i update **system.img** by **make snod**

then i try to restart emulator, or **adb remount adb sync**, or kill system_server process

but sadly, no matter what kinds of methods i use, the emulator always output the original string.(so angry)

i even extract the new output system.img to get the new services.odex file, and use oat2dex.jar to decompile it to java code, and i indeed see the string has changed in it.

so why when i run the emulator, it won't become effective...

Comment: Should it be `frameworks` instead of `framework` ?

Answer (score 1):

The system image file used by the emulator is `system-qemu.img`.
For some reason that file isn't made by `make snod`, which only makes `system.img`.  I think what is needed is an additional target so you could say `make qsnod` or something, but there doesn't seem to be one.  I don't know how anyone can work like this.

I don't understand the Makefile structure well enough at this point to figure out how to add a `qsnod` target, but here's a way to hand-roll
 `system-qemu.img`.

Notice that the very last step that `make -nN` reports is:

```
[100% 255/255] Create system-qemu.img
```

To find out what command it ran there, you can say `make showcommands -jN`.  I did this, and found it was the following, on my Macbook Pro:

```
[100% 255/255] /bin/bash -c "(export SGDISK=out/host/darwin-x86/bin/sgdisk; device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_qemu_image.sh out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img)"
```

So that's the command for making `system-qemu.img` from input `system.img` (which is what `make snod` makes).

So, my recipe for rebuilding `system.img` on my machine, after changing a .java file under framework/base, is:

```
mmm frameworks/base -jN
make snod -jN
SGDISK=out/host/darwin-x86/bin/sgdisk device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_qemu_image.sh out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img
```

Then when I restart the emulator, I see that my change has taken effect.